# On click of submit button of form A, form A should disappear, and in its place, form B should appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two forms, one is shown and the other is hidden. On click of submit button of form A, form A should disappear, and in its place, form B should appear.

In my code, On click of submit button(id="signup-btn1") of form "signup", form "signup" should hide and form "signup2" should show. They are both in exactly the same position according to the styles. It's just a matter of switching the first form content for the second.

The HTML is as follows:

```
           <div class="signup-form">
                <form class="signup" name="sign-up" method="post" action="">
                    <input type="email" name="signup-email" value="" placeholder="E-mail" class="signup-email" />
                    <input type="password" name="signup-password" value="" placeholder="Password" />
                    <input type="password" name="signup-confirmpassword" value="" class="c-password" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
                    <input type="submit" id="signup-btn1" name="signup-btn" value="Sign up" class="signup-btn" />
                </form>

                <form class="signup2" name="sign-up2" method="post" action="">
                    <h2>Step 2</h2>
                    <p>Please enter your school name to complete the sign up.</p>
                    <input type="text" name="school-name" value="" class="school-input" placeholder="School Name" />
                    <input type="submit" name="complete-signup" value="Complete Sign up" class="signup-btn" />
                </form>

            </div>
```

Using jQuery is preferred and should result in far less code. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place each form in a div, then:

```
$("button").click(function(){
$("#div1").toggle();
$("#div2").toggle();
})
```

Work if your page have only 2 above forms :)

Comment: Your explanations makes sense. Instead of having two different forms, I can make it into one form, with the first button being an anchor instead of a button, so that the form does not tries to submit. And when the anchor is clicked the rest of the form content is shown. And then at last we could submit. I shall try this and let you know if it works. Thanks :)

Comment: the first button cannot be an anchor. I made it into a div. Works beautifully